# Decomposing $g=xy$ where $\left|g\right|=\left|x\right|{\cdot}\left|y\right|$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Throughout, let us assume we are working with a finite group $G$. The order of an element $g\in G$ is denoted by $\left|g\right|$.

It is a standard exercise to prove that if $x, y\in G$ have relatively prime orders (i.e. $\gcd(\left|x\right|, \left|y\right|)=1$) and $xy=yx$, then $\left|xy\right| = \left|x\right|\cdot \left|y\right|$.

> What about the converse? If $g\in G$ has order $\left|g\right|=m\cdot n$, where
>   $\gcd(m, n)=1$, do there always exist elements $x, y\in G$ such that
>   $g=xy$, $xy=yx$, and $\left|x\right|=m$, $\left|y\right|=n$ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, $g^{am}$ and $g^{bn}$. Where $am+bn=1$ (by Bezout's lemma if you wish).

Comment: But is $|g^{am}|=n$? Not necessarily. We can only say $|g^{am}|$ divides $n$.

Comment: @Prism Since $am+bn=1$, $a$ is also relatively prime to $n$. That resolves the issue.

Comment: @alex.jordan: Oh yes… $|g^{am}| = |g|/\gcd(|g|, am) = mn/\gcd(mn, am) = mn/m = n$. Thanks both to you and PVAL!